# How to check TypeScript code for syntax errors from a command line?

Tags: typescript, syntax, compilation, verification, syntax-checking

I have a code that generates TypeScript classes, and as a build/test step, I would like to check the generated files for syntax correctness.

I have looked at [TypeScript compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) but see no such option.

- How can I check the syntax?

I don't want a full compilation because the referred types are not reachable at that build step (they are in a different module to which the generated sources are added later).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its just syntax checking you are after then you can use a linter like [tslint](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/) which can be run from the command line or via many build tools

Comment: Looks like TSLint is going to be deprecated in 2019, according to their [github page](https://github.com/palantir/tslint).  Apparently, ESLint along with @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin should do the trick.

Comment: It is deprecated now https://code.visualstudio.com/api/advanced-topics/tslint-eslint-migration

Answer (score 53):

The `tsc --noEmit` is what you're searching.

> Do not emit compiler output files like JavaScript source code, source-maps or declarations.

[source TSDocs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noEmit)

---

If you want lint code as well as check types on CI use `tsc --noEmit && eslint`

[source Stackoverflow comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60758789/9795603)

Comment: so annoying that --noEmit isn't the default option

Comment: tsc by default compile the project

Comment: You can use "tsc --noEmit --skipLibCheck" to ignore checking node_modules.

Answer (score 2):

First install ESLint (you need npm installed in your system):

```
npm i -g eslint
```

Execute ESLint to check files:

```
eslint file1.ts file2.ts
```

or:

```
eslint lib/**
```

ESLint supports a lot of options for more advanced case uses, [check the docs](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface).

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE! In some cases, using the compiler options to include and check JavaScript may get you where you need to be (or at least close enough that you could fix your JavaScript code)... when this doesn't get you where you want to be, the below answer will help.

There is no option that would check your files without being able to validate type information - although you could supply a definition file of very loose types to have those modules effectively ignored, for example:

```
declare var myModule: any;
```

This would supress any type checking against `myModule` and allow you to use the standard `tsc` command to check your files.

Comment: I think that this is about compilation errors. I only need a syntax check - i.e. the structure, keywords, parenthesis, etc. Just the AST. This can be done without type information.