# eslint not finding syntax errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, eslint, eslintrc

This is my `.eslintrc`:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "react": {
      "version": "detect"
    },
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": {
        "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"],
        "moduleDirectory": ["node_modules", "src/"],
      }
    }
  },
  "extends": [
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "prettier/@typescript-eslint",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended",
    "plugin:testing-library/recommended",
    "plugin:jest/recommended",
    "airbnb",
    "airbnb/hooks"
  ],
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es6": true,
    "jest": true
  },
  "globals": {
    "Atomics": "readonly",
    "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
  },
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2019,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    }
  },
  "plugins": [
    "react",
    "@typescript-eslint",
    "testing-library",
    "jest"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "import/extensions": 0,
    "import/prefer-default-export": 0,
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": [2, { "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"] }],
  },
}
```

And I'm trying to check if this causes an error in lint:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App test={test} />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

And obviously react build/yarn start gives this error (as it should):

> Type '{ test: It; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
> Property 'test' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.  TS2322

but lint doesn't. It just spews a couple of warnings about other things, and ignores this potentially huge problem. What's interesting, my editor (Webstorm) shows me the errors. But running `yarn lint`/`npm run lint` doesn't. Why? What am I missing in my `.eslintrc`?

I'm running lint with `eslint "src/**/*.{tsx, ts}" --fix`. And yes, the file in question is in the `src` directory.

Comment: That is a typescript error, not a linting error. So obviously the linter ignores it as the typescript compiler/language service is responsible for finding this.

Comment: TS2322 is a type error. Your linter doesn't check for these. Not all warnings and errors in webstorm come from eslint.

Comment: Wasn't this supposed to be a replacement for tslint? ` "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",`. If not is there a way to add type checking in lint?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60514929/eslint-not-reporting-typescript-compiler-type-checking-errors does this help?

Comment: Yup. Perfect. Thank you!